# Using recoil.js in react, in class component without using hooks

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I am new to recoil, and I am using all class components.
Here is my recoil state

```
export const tokenState = atom({
  key: "tokenState",
  default: "",
});
```

How to use recoil in class component and set the token?
I have used `RecoilRoot` in app as

```
<RecoilRoot>
  <Header />
  <Main />
</RecoilRoot>
```

In `login.js`, I want to set the token in recoil, but `login.js` is a class component.

```
const res = await APIS.login(apiRoute,requestObject);
```

In `res.data.token` I am getting the jwt token.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Bikram, is there anything wrong with Matt's or mine answers? Do you need any more info?

Comment: Works pretty well. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recoil.JS is meant to be used with react hooks, I don't think they provide any other functions other than hooks.
If you can't change Login.js to a functional component try using a wrapping functional component that passes the token as prop to the login.js component.

I'd suggest `useRecoilState(myAtom)`.

```
function LoginWrapper(props) {
    const [token, setToken] = useRecoilState(myAtom);

    useEffect(() => {
      async function get() {
         const { data: { token: jwt } } = await APIS.login(apiRoute,requestObject);

         setToken(jwt);
      }

      get();
    }, []);

    return <LoginComponent {...props} jwt={token} />
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As @Matt said, you must wrap your class component into a functional one that passes the Recoil APIs as a prop.

Anyway, if you want to set the atom' token from your `Login` component, you could simply wrap `Login` into a component that passes down the result of `useSetRecoilState`

```js
const LoginWrapper = () => {
  const setToken = useSetRecoilState(tokenState);
  return <Login setToken={setToken} />;
};
```

In case of more complex cases, you could leverage Recoil' [`useRecoilCallback`](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useRecoilCallback/) that allows you to consume the whole Recoil APIs at once

```js
const LoginWrapper = () => {
  const setToken = useRecoilCallback(({ set }) => token => {
    set(tokenState, token);
  });

  return <Login setToken={setToken} />;
};
```

> Please note: the main difference between using `setRecoilState` and `setRecoilCallback` is that using `setRecoilState` automatically subscribes the consuming component to the atom changes, while `setRecoilCallback` does not subscribe it so you could avoid some renders.

You can find both the solutions in this [working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-62860300-set-recoil-atom-in-class-component-473v0?file=/src/App.js). As you can see the `PrintToken` component re-renders correctly as soon as the `Login` component updates the token.

Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1:

call `RecoilNexus` at root file as `App.tsx` or `index.tsx`

```
return (
<RecoilNexus />
)
```

then, you can call `getRecoil` for get recoil state and `setRecoil` for set recoil state

```
import {setRecoil, getRecoil, getRecoilPromise, resetRecoil} from '@components/RecoilNexus';

export const tokenState = atom({
  key: "tokenState",
  default: "",
});


const onSetTokenState=setRecoil(tokenState)
onSetTokenState("abc")


const tokenRecoilState=getRecoil(tokenState)
console.log(tokenRecoilState)
```

**RecoilNexus.tsx**

```
import {RecoilValue, RecoilState, useRecoilCallback} from 'recoil';

interface Nexus {
  get?: <T>(atom: RecoilValue<T>) => T;
  getPromise?: <T>(atom: RecoilValue<T>) => Promise<T>;
  set?: <T>(
    atom: RecoilState<T>,
    valOrUpdater: T | ((currVal: T) => T),
  ) => void;
  reset?: (atom: RecoilState<any>) => void;
}

const nexus: Nexus = {};

export default function RecoilNexus() {
  nexus.get = useRecoilCallback<[atom: RecoilValue<any>], any>(
    ({snapshot}) =>
      function <T>(atom: RecoilValue<T>) {
        return snapshot.getLoadable(atom).contents;
      },
    [],
  );

  nexus.getPromise = useRecoilCallback<[atom: RecoilValue<any>], Promise<any>>(
    ({snapshot}) =>
      function <T>(atom: RecoilValue<T>) {
        return snapshot.getPromise(atom);
      },
    [],
  );

  nexus.set = useRecoilCallback(({set}) => set, []);

  nexus.reset = useRecoilCallback(({reset}) => reset, []);

  return null;
}

export function getRecoil<T>(atom: RecoilValue<T>): T {
  return nexus.get!(atom);
}

export function getRecoilPromise<T>(atom: RecoilValue<T>): Promise<T> {
  return nexus.getPromise!(atom);
}

export function setRecoil<T>(
  atom: RecoilState<T>,
  valOrUpdater: T | ((currVal: T) => T),
) {
  nexus.set!(atom, valOrUpdater);
}

export function resetRecoil(atom: RecoilState<any>) {
  nexus.reset!(atom);
}
```

## Solution 2:

Wrap the Function component around the Class component and pass the recoil state or setter function as a prop like this

```
function LoginCompnentWrapper(props) {
    const [token, setToken] = useRecoilState(myAtom);
    return <LoginComponent {...props} token={token} setToken={setToken} />
}
```